# Weird Localhost URL

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a question

when I run my website locally, the url on my web address looks like below

```
http://localhost:51403/(S(ywy2dtkxckf11vztxljddhp3))/Login.aspx?_height=899&_width=1280
```

what is the meaning of (S(ywy2dtkxckf11vztxljddhp3))??and how can I erase that thing??

My suggestion that because of IIS on my machine but don't know how to fix it

Thanks in advance for helping

Comment: That is because of cookieless session. Your session Id is `(S(ywy2dtkxckf11vztxljddhp3))`. See details in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479315.aspx).

Comment: and to erase it i need to disable my session state?

Comment: No, you can set `cookieless="UseCookies"`. Here are the settings:[sessionState Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: sir I got a new problem...the session won't be destroyed when I close the web except I end run of my iis

Comment: You can look at this article:[Beginner's Guide to ASP.NET Cookies](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31914/Beginner-s-Guide-To-ASP-NET-Cookies).